# How do you merge multiple paper.js layers into a single rasterized image?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

When a paper.js project has multiple layers, how do you merge them into a single rasterized image?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add all the items from all the layers in a group and rasterize it.